# Восстановление USB flash

Tags: linux, usb, восстановление, flash-память

Есть флешка, которая не определяется в системе как устройство хранения.

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 090c:3259 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.)
...
```

И, на этом всё. Ни lsblk, ни fdisk, ни прочие не видят устройства хранения.
При подключении устройства создаётся только:

```
/dev/bus/usb/003/009
```

Никаких /dev/sdX нет.

Есть ли способ восстановить работоспособность флешки?

Перемкнуть контакты для переключения в тестовый режим не могу, т.к. до них не добраться - корпус флешки металлический + минималистичный (лишнее движение и внутренности флешки будут повреждены).

Интерес здесь чисто "спортивный", т.к. данные я успел скопировать. Несколько лет назад я уже делал подобное, но в том случае, я смог добраться и замкнуть контакты для переключения в тестовый режим.

Нужно решение под Linux.

Если бы устройство виделось бы как /dev/sdX, то проблем не вызвало.

**UPD:**

Вот, что пишет **dmesg** при подключении.

```
[141303.086517] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[141303.214128] usb 3-7: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=3259, bcdDevice= 1.00
[141303.214140] usb 3-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[141303.214147] usb 3-7: Product: SM3259AA MEMORY BAR 
[141303.214154] usb 3-7: Manufacturer: Silicon Motion,Inc. 
[141303.217371] usb-storage 3-7:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[141303.218182] scsi host6: usb-storage 3-7:1.0
[141304.277224] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SMI      USB MEMORY BAR   1000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[141304.278373] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[141304.278539] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Хм, /dev/sdb всё же создался, но:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
dd: не удалось открыть '/dev/sdb': No medium found
```

**fdisk** тоже пишет "No medium found".

Comment: В dmesg пишут что-нибудь интересное?

Comment: вывод **dmesg** внёс в описание вопроса

Comment: Возможно, проблема связана с тем, что **hdparm** показывает, что секторов на устройстве 0. Может, есть возможность прописать их?

Comment: @Vitaly, низкоуровневое «восстановление» (перепрошивка контроллеров) флешек делается через утилиты производителя, обычно они реализуют какие-то свои протоколы… пару лет назад я сам  искал открытые решения — ничего готового не находил… как и никаких открытых спецификаций по оным протоколам… так что единственный вариантом остаётся реверс-инжениринг виндового софта, но это довольно сложно и затратно… если цель в том, чтобы принципиально обойтись без продуктов MS'а, то ЕМНИП у меня получалось запускать win-утилиты под виртуалкой с ReactOS'м (само собой ни каких обещаний воспроизводимости)…

Comment: Ну, как, принципиально. Для этого нужно ставить виртуалку, ставить винду. Хотелось бы быстрее. В принципе, я уже нашёл похожие темы, где так же предлагалось смотреть на сайте производителя. Самое сложное в том, что я уже не помню модель. Надеюсь VID/PID будет достаточно.